# How to setup a correct rampup time in Jmter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I have a scenerio in which i have to run one thread(containing lots of https request) with 10 user with rampup period 20 second, My reqesut are  as ,a request1 pass request2 a variable value and then link the record(one link per record). but what is happenig
since I am running it found that request 1 is passing variable value to request 2 and successfuly link the record, but in the subsequent requests I found that my request are getting failed on assertion because it is saying that request2 could not link because it is already linked with the request1. Note that If i run the thread for one user it is succefully passing the variable value to request 2 from request1 and succefully linking the record, no matter how much Time I run it for single thread(user). so the issue is some where between the timer.
WHATI WANT that for the second(THREAD)user it did not start the request 1 passing variable to request2 MECHANISM untill the user1's not passed the request2 variable value and succefully linked it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's connected with ramp-up time, the possible reasons are in:

1. Your test scenario doesn't implement [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) or parameterization is failing
2. The system under test doesn't support concurrent requests which sounds like a critical bug, you can try reproducing the issue with 2 users and a [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

Comment: thanks for the reply. it was my script that casuing the problem.